# Обычный post-запрос c json

Tags: java

Как я могу отправить обычный `post` - запрос с `json'ом` ? Никак не могу понять. Вот такая штука не работает (точнее работает, но отправляются не `json`, а данные):

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(stringUrl);

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "126927462"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Может ли кто-нибудь поправить мой код или привести пример того как надо правильно отправлять `json` `POST'ом` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UrlEncodedFormEntity`, вероятно, используется для отправки `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Попробуйте заменить

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "126927462"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```

на

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", "126927462");
obj.put("message", message);
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Код из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958182/android-http-post-with-parameters-not-working). Java не знаю, могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно создать JSON, например с [jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
Map<String, String> mapForJson = new HashMap<>();
mapForJson.put("id", "126927462");
mapForJson.put("message", message);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonData = mapper..writeValueAsString(mapForJson);
```

А для post-запрос c JSON можно использовать [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) построенный на apache http api.

```
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createPost(yourUri, String.class)
.responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer()).build();

public void send(){
  ResponseHandler<String> response = httpRequest.executeWithBody(jsonData);
  System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.get()); //returns response body
}
```

Настоятельно рекомендую прочитать документацию перед использованием.